# Logging errors in a single file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to log all applications errors in a single file.

I am configured the application to save logs with log4j, but I need a file that contains only error logs.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to use all different logging levels, but only write errors in the log file? Is this what you want?

Comment: @saadoune can you tell me ? what i replied is useful for you or not ?

Comment: vishal gajera, thank you for your answer i will implement now and answer you back, meanwhile, can you tell me if it is possible to have even a nullpointerexception for example that is not in printed by log.error(" ") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your log4j configuration file configure it likewise, for getting error into separate file,

```
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,INFO,FILE,ERROR_FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.file=${catalina.base}/logs/myApplicationLogs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n

    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.file=${catalina.base}/logs/ERROR_fileName.log
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.Threshold=ERROR
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.Append=true
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.ERROR_FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

getting error into separete file use from your code,

```
log.error("--- error text ---");
```

This will help you out to get error into separete file , i.e. `ERROR_fileName.log`

where as normal log print likewise,

```
log.debug("--- normal log text ----");
```